# calculate sales for previous dates (mid-month and end month) using DAX

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am very new to DAX and i want sum of sales for the previous months. As you can see, the dates are : The 15th of every month and the last day of every month. Can anyone please help me?

I want when i use the date as a filters , when i chose a date, i want the measure to give me the results of the previous date.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a calculated column that shows the "previous date" for each date. If that is successful then possibly you could return the result using the date from the "previous date" calculated column when the row with a date was selected.

Comment: 1)Yes, i have created a calculated column with the formula:PREVIOUS DATE = CALCULATE(MAX(SUMMARY[Date ]),FILTER(SUMMARY,SUMMARY[Date ]<EARLIER(SUMMARY[Date ])))
2) I calculate the measure using previous date with this:
PREV. RESULTS = 
VAR CurrentDate = MAX('SUMMARY'[PREVIOUS DATE])
VAR PrevDate = EDATE(CurrentDate,-12)
VAR RESULTS =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(SUMMARY[Chg Hrs])/SUM(SUMMARY[Standard Available Hrs]),
 FILTER(SUMMARY,LASTDATE(SUMMARY[PREVIOUS DATE])))
RETURN
RESULTS
 But i get the wrong results.

Comment: This leads me to think i did not understand your problem. If the user selects 30-sep you want the total for 30-sep added to the total for 15-sep added to the total for 30-sep ? or to you want to display the total for 30-sep in one column and the total for 15-sep in another. and do you want to display just the 2 dates... or the total for the selected date and all previous dates ?  are you trying to add together the results for all the dates in the same month ? or if 15-sep is selected do you want to add the results for 31-aug ?

Comment: No, if the user selects 30 september, i want in one column the results of 30 sep and on the other column, the result of 15-sep. I am able to calculate the results of the date selected but i cannot get the correct results for the previous date.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Thanks for posting this. Working on it has been very instructive. I've attached a copy of my power bi file and a pdf[image: picture of the report]

this may not be a solution you can use... it does show both amounts received during the month and the total for the month (months are displayed as numbers)

The core trick I used was to create 2 calculated columns for each row, one for the 15th the other for the end of the month. I populated them with a zero or the amount in the row depending on what the date field in the row looked like. that gave me amounts i could summarize.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hdM5QKonEft4sYk2yyD0JLlXJcEb3baU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I am gonna see if i can use your way of thinking to see if i can solve the issue. Once it is solved , i will get back in here and post the final solution. Thank you very much.